# How restore my Mac with boot camp partition from time machine

Tags: macos, time-machine, bootcamp, restore

I have my Mac boot camped with windows 7, unfortunately my hard drive was corrupted on the Mac partition, the windows partition is OK, I fixed the Mac partition but right now I can restore my Mac from time machine backup.
The time machine backup process works almost 40% and then stop and appear an error:

> An error occurred while restoring from backup.
>   Restart your computer and then try restoring again

Do I need to format all my hard drive and then restore my mac from time machine or is there other help available?

Answer (score 1):

I would try a two step restore to see if the problem is with the Mac Partition (likely) or the drive (hopefully not the case) or the backup (hopefully not the case).

1. Boot to recovery HD and erase the Mac partition (be careful of course to just delete the Mac data - not the entire drive with Windows side.)
2. Run OS installer and just install the OS.
3. When the setup assistant runs, then try to migrate data from the Time Machine drive. Keep it disconnected until after the OS install in step 2 finishes.

Also, you might look at the logs during installation (Command-L, Command-3) to watch for I/O errors on the drive to rule out hardware errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot! bmike, I will try and let you know what happen.